# What is correct Expected Behavior on Ipad/iphone of Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

With Winter'16 Upgrade, I see fluctuation in behavior of Salesforce

Using Ipad (Safari Browser) - When logged in, it automatically take me lightingin-forceinstead of showing desktop version of Salesforce, that too happens only in 2/5 sandboxes we own

[image: Safari Browser Loading Emulator on Login]

Using Ipad (Chrome Browser) - On login, we landup on Desktop version of Salesforce in ipad.

[image: Google Chrome Browser Loads Desktop Version of SFDC]

Question : What setting should I be changing to make behavior consistent on devices.

So far couldn't get a proper documentation on this behavior

Answer (score 1):

On Enabling setting with these steps

- From Setup, click Mobile Administration > Salesforce1 > Settings.
- Select Enable the Salesforce1 browser app to allow all users in your
  organization to access the app.
- Deselect this option to turn off access to the app. Click Save.

After enabling, SFDC only enables for Safari not for Chrome, I learned chrome in not a supported browser for iOS (devices)

See below 
[image: Chrome not Listed]

Read more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf1_requirements.htm)